# Evaluate button value in directive - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following button:

```
    <button
        class="btn"
        style="width: 67px; text-align: left"
        ng-class="{'mypre' : step==1, 'mynext': step==2}"
        ng-click="submit()"
        ng-disabled="_wait"
        in-dots="_wait">
        {{ step == 1 ? 'Next': 'Save' }}
    </button>
```

Directive in-dots adds dots while loading. Here it is:

```
directive('inDots', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var text = element.text().trim();
        var dots = '';

        var addDot = function () {
            if ('...' == dots) {
                dots = '';
            }
            else {
                dots += '.';
            }

            if (scope.$eval(attrs.inDots)) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    addDot();
                }, 300);
            }
            else {
                dots = '';
            }

            element.text(text + dots);

        };

        scope.$watch(attrs.inDots, function (value) {
            if (value) {
                addDot();
            }
        });


    }
}])
```

The problem is that `element.text()` is not evaluated. How can I evaluate it?
It tried scope.$eval(element.text()), but it gives me error.
Maybe because step is not in correct scope? If yes, then how can I resolve it?

Comment: Just to eliminate other possibilities... are you sure the code itself is running, and it's not just `element.text()` that's messing up? Is `attrs.inDots` the proper value, does `_wait` get evaluated? A plunker would help!

Comment: why even mess with the other text and not put directive on another span inside button after the text? Or just append a span and manipulate it

Comment: element.text() outputs unevaluated button value. I write such code, because I'm a newbie and don't know effective techniques.